# Are there any dataset for psychology

Tags: linked-data, rdf, ontology

I am looking for a triple RDF dataset or vocabulary for a psychology website I am developing. I have a large XML schema database and am looking to translate this database to one RDF serialization format. I've searched for websites that have vocabulary such as lov.okfn.org/dataset/lov, but could not find any related vocabulary to translate the data.

Are there any website or methodology that have such a triple data store for the website?  Any suggestions on building an open data triplestore for such purposes?

Comment: Welcome to Open Data SE! Could you please provide more details about what exactly you are looking for? What would you like to do with the data?

Comment: Hello Patrick, I have a big xml schema database and looking to translate this database to one RDF serialization format .. I search for a websites that has vocabulary such as http://lov.okfn.org/dataset/lov/.. but I could not find any related vocabulary to translate the data..

The website that am talking about have articles and information about the articles .. so how can I build triple data format for the xml files that I have ?

Comment: Would it be possible to provide a link to the website you mentioned? Could you post an example of your existing XML database? Either would help a lot. Also, please integrate what you just wrote into your main question to make it clearer – thanks :)

Comment: Do you consider Psychiatric Genomics to be 'psychology'?  If so, http://www.med.unc.edu/pgc/downloads  (found via http://www.nimh.nih.gov/about/director/2013/open-data.shtml )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Thesaurus of Psychological Index Terms](http://www.apa.org/pubs/databases/training/thesaurus.aspx), published by one of your employer's (?) customers, is known now as [Psychology Ontology](https://bioportal.bioontology.org/ontologies/APAONTO?p=summary).

This ontology is not even a taxonomy, but rather a [flat list](https://bioportal.bioontology.org/ontologies/APAONTO/?p=classes&conceptid=http%3A%2F%2Fontology.apa.org%2Fapaonto%2FtermsonlyOUT%2520(5).owl%23Fear&jump_to_nav=true) of classes.

BioPortal [provides](https://bioportal.bioontology.org/ontologies/APAONTO/?p=mappings) mappings between this ontology and many other ontologies.

Additionally, BioPortal contains other ontologies published by APA:

[image: BioPortal search]

The [OntoPsychia ontology](https://bioportal.bioontology.org/ontologies/ONTOPSYCHIA) seems very interesting, but is not available for download.

---

AberOWL repository provides these links:

- [MFOEM - Emotion Ontology](http://aber-owl.net/ontology/MFOEM#!http%3A%2F%2Fpurl.obolibrary.org%2Fobo%2FBFO_0000004)
- [MF - Mental Functioning Ontology](http://aber-owl.net/ontology/MF#!http%3A%2F%2Fpurl.obolibrary.org%2Fobo%2FGO_0007610)
- [MFOMD - MFO Mental Disease Ontology](http://aber-owl.net/ontology/MFOMD#!http%3A%2F%2Fpurl.obolibrary.org%2Fobo%2FMFOMD_0000024)
- [NBO - Neuro Behavior Ontology](http://aber-owl.net/ontology/NBO#!http%3A%2F%2Fpurl.obolibrary.org%2Fobo%2FNBO_0000539)